# why is the pattern being printed along with the matches in RegEx.Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bit of regular expression issue in c#.

My Code

```
string str ="1+44+(2+3)";
string pattern = @"((\d+)|[+*-/()])";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(str,pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

each match is written on a new line, but for the sake of saving space ill separate each match with " , " instead.

I expect the result printed to be:

1 , + , 44 , + , ( , 2 , + , 3 , )

but i get (delimter is included for some reason):

1 , + , 44 , + , ( , 2 , + , 3 , ) , ( , ( , \ , d , + , ) , | , [ , + , * , - , / , ( , ) , ] , )

So how do i avoid including the delimiter in the result.

Comment: See https://repl.it/Co7O, I'm getting the expected results.

Comment: Actually, I cannot understand how you get the *pattern* split the way you show. Of course, there is an issue with the regex, `-` must be at the start or end of the character class, or escaped (`((\d+)|[+*/()-])`). However, it has nothing to do with your pattern being split.

Comment: i am pretty sure that when +,*,/ and so on is placed within [ ] they are treated as symbols and no need for escaping them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is correct. i however had completly missed another for loop further down from some old experiment. that is what happens when you get stressed.

i am sorry for wating your time